# Derangements of multisets

Tags: combinatorics, multisets, derangements

> Find the number of ways a string of numbers (that may contain similar items) can be deranged, so that a number is not placed in the same place as it or its similar numbers were placed.
>
> For example, $\{0,0,0,1,1,1\}$ can be arranged in only one way, and that is $\{1,1,1,0,0,0\}$.
>
> $\{0,0,0,1,1,1,1\}$ cannot be arranged in any way.
>
> $\{1,2,2,14\}$ can be arranged in $2$ ways, i.e $\{2,1,14,2\}$, $\{2,14,1,2\}$.
>
> $\{1,1,2,2,14\}$ can be arranged in $5$ ways, i.e $\{2,2,1,1,14\}$, $\{14,2,1,1,2\}$, $\{2,2,14,1,1\}$, $\{2,2,1,14,1\}$, $\{2,14,1,1,2\}$.

Please do try and respond. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is in [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Generalizations).

Comment: marvis thank you for the edit, @joriki tht was incredile stuff by you. However for words made up of two different letters the answer was pretty simple, but i could not figure out the answer for more no. of numbers. Integrations I am familiar with. but in that secion it says for a certain sequence of polynomials P.. I didnt understand how to implement that P, and what could be the possible x value. A little more clarification on this will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question confuses multisets for tuples (with repeated elements). A multiset does not assign an order to its elements, therefore a permutation of its elements is meaningless.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is given in [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Generalizations): Up to a sign, the number of such derangements is given by

$$\int_0^\infty L_{n_1}(x)\cdots L_{n_r}(x)\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx\;,$$

where $r$ is the number of items, $n_i$ is the number of occurrences of item $i$ and $L_k$ is the $k$-th [Laguerre polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials). For instance, for $1,1,2,2,14$, we have $r=3$, $n_1=2$, $n_2=2$, $n_3=1$, so up to a sign the number of derangements is

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty L_2(x)L_2(x)L_1(x)\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx
&=
\int_0^\infty \frac12(x^2-4x+2)\frac12(x^2-4x+2)(1-x)\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx
\\
&=
\int_0^\infty\left(-\frac14x^5+\frac94x^4-7x^3+9 x^2-5x+1\right)\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx
\\
&=-4\;.
\end{align}
$$

This indicates an error in your example, and indeed, the arrangement $2,2,1,1,14$ is not a derangement since the $14$ is in the same place.

Comment: I m spell bound!! Thank you.. :) Got a crystal clear idea..

Comment: (+1) In fact, the sign is $(-1)^{2+2+1}=-1$.

Comment: How would you calculate the number of partial derangements?