# Solitaire probability

Tags: probability

I would like to know the exact probability of the following game. I start counting from one to 13 and do this totally four times. On each turn I say a number and turn a card from a deck. Ace is considered to be as 1. If on one turn I say the same number as it is on the card, I lose. What is my winning probability?

Comment: Try using the inclusion exclusion principle

Comment: Not exactly $\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^{52}\approx 0.01557$ but probably that order of magnitude.

Comment: More or less? Interesting problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact answer is

$$P(win) = \frac{\int_0^{\infty}L_4^{13}(x)e^{-x}dx}{52!/(4!)^{13}} \approx 1.6233\%$$

Where $L_4(x)$ is the 4th [Laguerre](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html) polynomial.  The numerator is the number of derangements of a multiset with 13 different elements each repeated 4 times, and it is from *[Derangements and Laguerre Polynomials](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2128316&fileId=S0305004100052154)* by S. Even and J. Gillis and described in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147657/derangements-of-multisets). Also a short derivation using rook polynomials can be found in [Laguerre polynomials and derrangements](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2076772) by D.M. Jackson.  The denominator of course is total permutations of the deck where we ignore suit.  This exact game was also analyzed in *[On the Asymtotic Behavior of a Card Matching Prob](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691467?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)*lem by Knudsen and Skau.

Comment: Indeed, the probability is exactly $\frac{4610507544750288132457667562311567997623087869}{284025438982318025793544200005777916187500000000}$