# Dealing cards, derangements, and probability: Is the Riddler Express solution incorrect?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

**Edit.** The error was noted in a subsequent [**Riddler entry**](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-long-will-it-take-to-blow-out-the-birthday-candles/) with a reference to an earlier MSE post:

[image]

---

The most recent [**Riddler Express**](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/dont-throw-out-that-calendar/) says:

[image]

But suppose you had this same question with only one suit (say, hearts): What is the probability that you get through the 13 hearts *without* what you say ever matching what you deal?

It seems to me that the method above would suggest computing $(12/13)^{13} = 0.3532\ldots$

This cannot be right, though; the modified question is essentially asking about [**derangements**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) for a set of $13$ elements. Checking the derangement sequence at [**OEIS**](https://oeis.org/A000166) yields as its thirteenth term $2290792932$; among the $13!$ combinations, this would yield a probability of winning the modified game equal to $2290792932/13! = 0.3678\ldots$

The numbers are not *very* different, but they are certainly different.

**Back to the main question:**

> Is the solution for the "Riddler Express" above incorrect? [I strongly believe it is...]
>
> **If so:** What is the correct solution, and how does one show this?

I had thought it would require a modification of the derangement formula using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle or some such thing (cf. [**this MO answer**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21019) from Richard Stanley). In fact, I computed it as $0.01623\ldots$ Again, this is "about 1.6 percent" (as in the solution write-up) but the methods are very different and the actual numerical results are *not* the same.

Am I overthinking? Is the Riddler underthinking? What gives?

Comment: You are correct; and I too am at little miffed at The Riddler for publishing this as the 'correct' answer (as opposed to a 'pretty good' answer).

Comment: @ChasBrown Thanks for the confirmation; I spent a bit of time last week trying to find an "express" solution, but (as suggested in my question) I view the 538 puzzle as *harder* than enumerating derangements, which is already pretty tough stuff...

Comment: The exact value is given in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340355/solitaire-probability) with citations to back it up.  It is close to the Riddler answer, but not equal.

Comment: Have you (or anyone else) emailed Oliver Roeder about the error? It should be done, but ideally only once.

Comment: @MarkS. You can find the error acknowledged in the most recent Riddler entry. See the edit to this post for a direct link. (It mentions the earlier [**MSE 1891958**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891958/).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of $P(win) = \frac{\int_0^{\infty}L_4^{13}(x)e^{-x}dx}{52!/(4!)^{13}} \approx 1.6233\%$
 is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340355/solitaire-probability) with citations.

Comment: (Where $L_4$ is the fourth [Laguerre Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html)...)

Comment: Thanks for the that, Ross! I guess I'd rather say, the Riddler's is close to the correct answer, but not equal :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the "Riddler Express" solution is not correct, but it is a reasonably good approximation.

Answer (score 3):

You can see that it is not correct by looking at the simpler case of an eight-card deck with A2 in each suit. To get zero matches, you need precisely 2A2A2A2A; the chance of this is exactly

$$\frac12 \times \frac47 \times \frac12 \times \frac35 \times \frac12 \times \frac23 \times \frac12 =\frac{1}{70}$$

But according to the Riddler's flaky logic, it would be
$$\left(\frac12\right)^8=\frac{1}{256}$$

Comment: This is a nice example; thanks. Thinking beyond your full suited 2-card deck to a full suited 3-card deck already indicates how difficult this problem is!