# Derangement formula for repeated permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

I need general formula for repeated permutation:

For any set of $n$ numbers $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, the formula for its number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) is given by the recursion $$!n=(n-1)(!(n-1)+!(n-2)).$$ Here, the numbers are distinct from one another (no number is repeated in the set).

Is there any general formula for the number of derangements when the numbers are repeated? For example, for a multiset like $ \{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5\} $.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: If you find a few more terms, [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C4%2C5&language=english&go=Search) might give you an answer.

Comment: Is $!n$ different from $n!$ (i.e. just the regular factorial function)?

Comment: No. !n means Number of derangement for n. n! means factorial n. @ gen-z.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derangements of multisets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147657/derangements-of-multisets)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a formula for counting these generalized derangements. It is due to Even and Gillis and it is in terms of products of Laguerre polynomials. See e.g. [this](http://people.brandeis.edu/%7Egessel/homepage/papers/rookp.pdf) paper by Gessel for a derivation from rook theory (p.4).  Let $$l_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k { n \choose k}^2 k! x^{n-k},$$ and define $\Phi$ to be the linear function on polynomials mapping $x^n$ to $n!$. It's shown that $$\Phi\left( \prod_{i=1}^r l_{n_i}(x)\right)$$
is the number of permutations of $n_1 + \cdots + n_r$ colored elements, with $n_i$ of the $i$-th color, so that no element is mapped to an element of the same color.

Here all elements are labeled, so the elements in a given color class are distinguishable, but if you don't want that just divide by $\prod_{i=1}^r n_i!$ to account for the permutations of each color class. And if you want a more compact formula, note that $\Phi(p(x)) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} p(x)\,dx$.

Edit: Here are some more details.

**First, an example of using this formula.**  The first few polynomials $l_n(x)$ are

\begin{align*}
l_0(x) &= 1\\
l_1(x) &= x - 1\\
l_2(x) &= x^2 - 4x + 2\\
l_3(x) &= x^3 - 9x^2 + 18x - 6.
\end{align*}

Now let's find the number of permutations of $1234$ where $1,2$ are colored red and $3,4$ are colored blue and no element can map to another with the same color.  Since there are $2$ of each color, we get $$l_2(x)l_2(x) = (x^2 - 4x + 2)(x^2 -4x + 2) = x^4 - 8x^3 + 20x^2 - 16x + 4.$$

Then we just apply $\Phi$, which means replacing each variable $x^k$ with $k!$.  We get

\begin{align*}
\Phi(l_2(x)l_2(x)) &= 1 \cdot 4! - 8 \cdot 3! + 20 \cdot 2! - 16 \cdot 1! + 4 \cdot 0!\\
&= 4.
\end{align*}

This corresponds to the $4$ permutations $3412, 4312, 3421, 4321$ with no element of $\{1,2\}$ mapping to another element of $\{1,2\}$ and similarly no element of $\{3,4\}$ mapping to another element of $\{3,4\}$.

If you want the number of derangements of the multiset $1122$ where the $1$s and $2$s are not distinguishable, just divide take this answer and divide by $2! \cdot 2!$ to get $1$, corresponding to the single word $2211$.

**As for the proof** - I will not give it entirely, but I will give the main ingredients.  (Note: We use $[n]$ to mean the set $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ and $[m,n]$ to mean $\{m, m+1, \ldots, n-1, n\}$.)

1. There is a well-known formula from rook theory, proven using inclusion-exclusion. If $B$ is a "board", a subset of the $n \times n$ grid $[n] \times [n]$, then let $r_k$ be ways of placing $k$ elements on the board $B$ with no two in the same row or column (i.e., the number of ways of placing $k$ rooks from chess that cannot attack each other.) Then $$\sum_{k} (-1)^k r_k (n-k)!$$ is the number of permutations $\sigma \in S_n$ with no $\sigma(i) = j$ for $(i,j) \in B$; that is, no $1$s on the set $B$ when you write the adjacency matrix.  You can write this as $\Phi(p_B(x))$ where $$p_B(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k r_k x^{n-k}$$ is the "rook polynomial" for $B$. (Note this is a variant of the usual definition of rook polynomial.)
2. If $$B_1 \subseteq [n_1] \times [n_1], B_2 \subseteq [n_2]\times[n_2],$$ let $B_1 \oplus B_2$ be board in $[n_1 + n_2] \times [n_1 + n_2]$ given by the disjoint union of $B_1$ with the translate of $B_2$ to the upper-right square $[n_1+1, n_1 + n_2] \times [n_1+1, n_1 + n_2]$. Then $p_{B_1}(x) p_{B_2}(x) = p_{B_1 \oplus B_2}(x)$. Inductively we get $p_{B_1}(x) \cdots p_{B_k}(x) = p_{B_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus B_k}(x)$, the rook polynomial for the board given by the block-diagonal board $B_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus B_k$.
3. Show that if $B$ is the whole board $[n] \times [n]$ then $p_B(x) = l_n(x)$ given above.
4. Note that if we have boards $B_i = [n_i] \times [n_i]$ for some $n_i$, permutations of $[n_1 + \cdots + n_k]$ avoiding the block-diagonal $B_1 \oplus B_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus B_k$ are exactly the generalized derangements: no $i \in B_l$ can map to $j \in B_l$ for any $l$.  Then we count these by applying 1, 2, 3 above.

Comment: Thanks  @Jair Taylor. I tried to study the references but need time (as complex functions and formulas). Do you have any easy reference for this derangement?

Comment: I don't know of an easier reference off the top of my head.  You could look at the original 1975 paper of Even and Gillis, but I haven't been able to find that for free online. If it helps I can give some more detail / example later. The proof uses inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Incidentally, while googling I found [this](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPS/gillis.ps) nice summary of how Gillis "accidentally" solved this problem over the course of over forty years.

Comment: @Tahid I added some details above, hopefully it's more helpful now.

Comment: For the time being, i have understood and checked the result with theory from your given explanation. Fantastic. As a author, Do you have any research paper to cite in my research article? Thanks

Comment: @Tahid - Glad to be helpful.  No, I don't have any relevant writeup other than this post.  I'd just cite the references I gave, or other references that Gessel gives for this problem.

Comment: Hi Jair, Do u have any references/clue for partial derangement (rencontre number) with above repeated numbers. For instance, we have n=1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6.  Instead of derangement of all n (=1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6) numbers, we will calculate for partial derangement ( for P<n number)of 1,1,2,2,3,3,4 numbers.    Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tahid Not sure what you mean.  What's a partial derangement? You could always post another question.

Comment: This is amazing!  When I was a college freshman, this problem occurred to me:  You turn over the cards of a shuffled deck, announcing Ace, 2, 3, ..., Jack, Queen, King, Ace, 2,.... as you turn over the cards.  What is the probability that you never turn the card you call for the whole $52$ cards? I was never able to do it, but about $15$ years later, I read about rook polynomials in an undergraduate book on combinatorics, and solved the problem by the methods of the text, which is precisely what is described above.  I didn't make so neat a formula, though.

Comment: @saulspatz And what's more: the likelihood of your outcome is about $e^{-4}$, and approaches this value as the number of cards in each suit tends to infinity.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, indeed.

Comment: @JairTaylor Hello Jair, can you help me with this one kind of problems, where only selective letters are deranged, can we apply those formulas here ? For example : How many permutations of 1,... 8 are there in which no even number appears in its natural position? Or even one more interesting problem "BHI BHV" here BHV have to be deranged but BHI have no restriction.

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar You can use rook theory to answer these kinds of questions, but I'm not going to do it here.  You can ask it as a separate question, if it is not a duplicate (I may or may not comment/answer.)

Comment: @JairTaylor I'll post a fresh new question with all details. thanks for replying! : )

Comment: @JairTaylor Plz can you help me figure out how to tackle such problems using Rooks formula , now I have asked a fresh question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731683/732073 .Your help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!