# Derangement and anagrams

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How can I calculate the amount of deranged anagrams for specific word.
For example, the word: Anona.
I know that there are $\frac{5!}{2!2!1!} = 30$ anagrams.
How can I calculate the amount of derangements: 
$$
oanan\
noaan\
nanao\
naaon
$$
Is there any general formula in order to deal with more sophisticated cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is a formula. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323743/derangement-formula-for-repeated-permutation/).

Comment: @JairTaylor Excellent answer.  I didn't know about this, and was just starting to write an answer explaining rook polynomials when your comment appeared, just in time!

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks! It is a gem of a formula.

Comment: For this particular problem, you could define $A_i$ to be the set of arrangements in which the $i$th position is a fixed point.  You could calculate the number of derangements by subtracting $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5|$ from the $30$ possible anagrams of ANONA by using the Inclusion-Exclusion Priniciple.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig what would the formula for calculating the union of arrangements be?

Comment: Also can we solve this by saying that a set Ai can be a combination of two positions? For example in this case we say Ai can be positions 1 and 3?

Comment: @JashShah $$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5| = \sum_{i = 1}^{5} |A_i| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 5} |A_1 \cap A_2| + \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 5} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k < l \leq 5} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5|$$ There are five terms in the first and fourth summations and ten terms in the second and third summations.  As for $A_1 \cap A_3$, this means the first and third positions are fixed points, so we have a word of the form Axoxa, where x represents one of the remaining letters.