# Derangement of letters with repitition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

The question is :
Number of Derangement possible for,
"ABHIBHAV".

But my concern is not solving only typically this problem, but to solve any derangement problem.

I recently came to know that these problem can be easily solved with Rooks polynomial, which intrigued me alot coz as such these problem require a greater thinking skills and I was amazed to know how is rooks polynomial solving this problem.

Then I posted one question on this website only (which is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3557228/732073))

After reading that I found that such problem are solved this way:
(Bcoz I absolutely could not get any "good","easy" AND "standard" articles which could make my understanding clear, yes those 3 words are with respect to me ..you may consider me as dumb)

So here is the solution I found :(Using rooks polynomial)

"ABHIBHAV" here I and V as single entity so $L1^2$ and there are three pair of letters A,B,H means $L2^3$

$L1^2 = (x-1)^2$

$L2^3 = (x^2-4x+2)^3$

So this is the reason behind the above
$$L_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k { n \choose k}^2 k! x^{n-k},$$

How these terms come?
(No one better can explain than [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3323743/732073) beautifully written answer to similar problem..)

Now to get the derangemnts I am actually suppose to first multiply those big polynomial equation so as to get another polynomial which ofcourse is too too too much work..
Then after multiplying those two things
I get one more huge equation (here) an 8th power equation..

So calculation:
$x^8 - 14 x^7 + 79 x^6 - 232 x^5 + 386 x^4 - 376 x^3 + 212 x^2 - 64 x + 8$
(9 terms)

Doesn't it seem to be too much multiplication. Is this the right way to solve these by this too lengthy polynomial multiplication method
So the answer comes like this
$$answer=8!-14.7!+79.6!-232.5!+386.4!-376.3!+212.2!-64.1!+8.0!=772$$

Now this is what I learned how I learned  from  The methods I read.

(The procedure I am telling is my interpretation of the answers on the questions I linked...bcoz I had mentioned that I didn't find any good and easy source so having confusion with the basics )

So my actually question is, is this all what rooks theorem is?
Bcoz I have put up a recent question as a doubt which you find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731683/732073)  where the answerer, gave me really a true insight of what actually is rooks theorem thus I realized that the whole rooks theorem is based on Chess board.
So Now if I were asked a question to derange the letters of word "abc" (has nothing to do with "ABHIBHAV", just a simple demo)
I would take a chess board of 3x3 dimension

So here in the chess board (1,1), (2,2),(3,3) are considered forbidden.
(Bcoz Derangement)
Now computing rooks polynomial and proceeding as per answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3731747/732073)  I get exactly the total number of derangements needed.

But when I proceed for the problem mentioned "ABHIBHAV".

Then how should the chess board be modelled to solve this problem.
Bcoz here I have repitition of letters!

**Any help of intuition to proceed / some extra links would be much appreciated!**

*(And one more thing:
I am really missing some points and having a gap in my understanding of this concept and it's application..to solve question, so plz suggest any easy material (if possible) for further read..bcoz already I have the original research paper which is some how complex to read for me)*

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727666

Comment: Oh yes sorry I was so involved In this problem that I forgot to search about it and wrote all my doubt as a fresh question...

Comment: Please don't close under duplicate anyone I am going to myself answer the very specific doubt I had so that future people who would see would get that doubt easily...And yes if any one wants to answer this question feel free to do it...!